# What's the meaning of @! in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Looking at sessions in Oracle I found a query with a syntax like this:

```
select *
from table
where tms_event > trunc(sysdate@!)
```

I ran

```
select sysdate@!
from dual
```

and it works (it looks like sysdate to me) but I can't find info about the meaning of @!

Edit: the original query originated on a remote database via db-link